# Where is the SP metadata xml in jhipster-generated app?

Tags: jhipster, saml, okta

I've created an app using JHipster with Okta integration.  I have it working against my own free Okta server, and now it is time to integrate with my customer's server.  They are asking me for my SP metadata xml, the List of attributes to be sent in samlresponse, and the Unique identifier to be passed in saml subject nameid.  I had thought that the unique identifier was something that they would give to me, and I would put in my config file.  I don't know where to find the other pieces.

Where do I find or generate the pieces they are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

JHipster supports Okta, but only via OIDC. It does not support Okta's SAML integration out-of-the-box.